# Outputting Dollars instead of English pound sign

Tags: magento-1.9, currency

I am outputting the difference between the sub total and the free delivery limit and i'm using this line to out put the currency

```
<?php $currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol()?>
```

But it keeps outputting a $ instead of £, how can i change it as i need it to change depending on where the user is in the world?

If i haven't been clear please just let me know and will try to elaborate more for you.

thank you

Comment: Could you please <?php echo '<br/>Currency Code : '.$_code; ?> ? If it prints USD then no wonder why you get $. You need to pass the right currency code to get the desired currency symbol. So in your case it is EUR for euro symbol.

Comment: But i want it to return what ever currency the customer is using? I thought it was why it had the getLocale?

Comment: just check my answer below, it returns the current store's currency symbol. I just replace your variable $_code with Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(). It returns the customer's store currency code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this and check

```
<?php 
    //returns current store's currency symbol
    $currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol() 

?>
```